# How to Avoid Repeatedly loading single image in Network tab using chrome browser

Tags: html, css

```css
.payble25 {
    background-position: -57px -27px;
    background-size: 35em;
}
.spt25 {
    background-image: url(images.svg);
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0;
    display: block;
    background-size: 30em;
    font-size: 12px!important;
}
```

```html
I am facing issue on chrome updated version(78.0) loading image multiple time from memory cache.

I have using css, html and sprite image in my application. This loading single image in Network tab using chrome browser.

I tried and apply image path like url(images?ver=1.0.svg), url(images?cache=none.svg); and url(images?1.0.svg);. but it is not resolved.



<span class="payble25 spt25"></span>
```

[Network tab image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vpWTv.png)

Answer (score 0):

You could encode the svg into base64 (there are a lot of free online services that'll do this for you) then use a data URI in your CSS background property.

```
background: url(data:image/gif;base64,<YourImageData>);
```

But there's really no performance penalty from loading it from memory, is there?